# Android remove EditText selection

Tags: android, android-edittext, xamarin.android

[image]

I have 2 `editText`s, whenewer I launch app first(orange) edit text is getting selected automaticaly.

I tried clear focus, but this hadn't worked for me.

```
               <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/event_title"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:inputType="textPersonName"
                            android:hint="@string/edit_text_title" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/txtInputLayoutPassword"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/event_description"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                            android:hint="@string/edit_text_description" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
```

> How to make first edit text look like second ?

Comment: Sometimes clearing focus isn't enough because the system (Android) doesn't know who to give the focus to. Take parent layout, `LinearLayout` and call `requestFocus()` on that view after you call `clearFocus()` on the `EditText`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                   <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <!-- Dummy item to prevent AutoCompleteTextView from receiving focus -->
                          <LinearLayout
                          android:focusable="true" 
                          android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                          android:layout_width="0px" 
                          android:layout_height="0px"/>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/event_title"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:inputType="textPersonName"
                            android:hint="@string/edit_text_title" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/txtInputLayoutPassword"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/event_description"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                            android:hint="@string/edit_text_description" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `ViewGroup` focusable in touch mode.
Like this from your code:

```
   <LinearLayout
   style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: Don't work to, maybe it's because I use this in bottomsheet which I pull up before? Then I would need code line to deselect it.